# Algorithm to find free rooms into a time schedule given a time

Tags: algorithm, time

that's the problem:

I have a list of events hosted in many rooms in different times. I'm given an hour of the day, let's say 16.30 and I want to show from the given time, to 1 hour after, all rooms that are free to use (no events hosted).
When I return the rooms I should also return:

- if they're free from now to a time (if the room was already free before the time interval)
- if they're free from a time to a time (if the room frees during the time interval)

Giving back in both cases the room name with the needed timestamps.

For now I thought about iterating into all the events, see where they are hosted, and remove these rooms from the rooms list. Then I'd just return the remaining rooms.

The point is that I can't really figure out how this would be possible to solve also returning the time interval during which the room is free

Any idea would be appreciated, thanks for your help.

Comment: If you want reasonable help, post your code and mark your problem specifically. Here is some general thought: "For every room, you could keep a boolean flag `freeFromNow` that you initially set to `true` and when an event in that room is encountered, you set it to `false`. Also, for every room, you can keep a time value for when the room becomes free."

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still working on the code so I don't think it could be of great help. Sorry.
The point is that, with the solution you suggested, I could easily return when a room frees, that's true, but not the time interval in which the room is free.
For example, in case a room frees during the time i asked for, I should return "it will be free from 'time' to 'time'", where the second time I get would be the one from the beginning of the next event hosted in the room.

Comment: Not a problem: set a `fromTime` to now and set a `toTime` to "now + 100 years" or whatever you want to have if it's free "forever". Then, when going through the events, update both times when necessary.